# Access originally clicked element in jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following plugin, and while I wish it to be able to be applied to multiple elements, I do not wish to create a new dialog for each element.

But in the dialog.open callback or when the button is clicked, I wish to be able to access the element which was clicked and opened the dialog.

If I wanted to create multiple dialogs, I suppose I could put `this.each(function () {...}` in the `init` method and then `this` would be the individually clicked element, but as stated earlier, I only one one dialog.

EDIT.  I revised the code so that it does what I need it to do.  It just seems like a bit of a hack using `data` as I did.  Is there a more proper way to do so?

How is this accomplished?

```
(function($){
    var defaults = {};

    var methods = {
        init : function (options) {

            var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

            var dialog = $('<div/>').dialog({
                open: function( event, ui ) {
                    console.log(dialog.data('elementThatWasClicked'));
                },
                buttons: [
                    {
                        text: 'click',
                        click: function() {console.log(dialog.data('elementThatWasClicked'));}
                    }
                ]

            });

            return this.each(function () {
                var $this=$(this);
                $this.click(function(){dialog.data('elementThatWasClicked',$this).dialog('open')});

            });
        }
    };

    $.fn.test = function(method) {
        if (methods[method]) {
            return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof method === 'object' || ! method) {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error('Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.test');
        }    
    };
    }(jQuery));

$(function(){
    $('.bla').test();
});
```

Comment: try printing out $(this) within click function.

Comment: @HieuLe  That is the correct element (and so is `$thumbnail` in the `this.each` loop), but how do I access it in the dialog script.  I suppose I could use `data` to tie it to the element, but I expect there is a more proper way to do so.

Comment: so youre asking about the open() method rigtht? I would suggest putting a breakpoint in there and look at the event object. Perhaps event.originalTarget would work.

Comment: @HieuLe  Don't have an `event.originalTarget`.  Have an `event.target`, but it is the dialog itself.

Comment: hmm yeah i see it now. What are you trying to use the button for within open()? Could you just do it directly within `$(this).click(function(){dialog.dialog('open'); <do stuff to button here> });`

Comment: @HieuLe  I don't think so as the `do stuff to button here` is in the callbacks.  My intent is when the dialog is opened, I get the `src` of the element that was clicked, and update the content in the dialog.  When the button is later clicked, I update the `src` of the element that opened the dialog.  I revised the original script so it does what I need it to do.  It just doesn't seem like the "right" way of doing it.

Comment: idk looks fine to me.